# relation does not exist 42P01

Tags: postgresql

I am getting folowwing error when execute my *stored procedure*. Does anyone knows how can i solve this issue? The table mentioned in error is always the same and it's the first one from the top of the list from my schema.

**This is my error:**

```
 relation "t_ser_d2ert" does not exist 42P01
```

**This is my stored procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schem.myprocedure()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
sessionPid numeric = pg_backend_pid();
BEGIN       

    
    begin
        raise notice 'schem.myprocedure()';
    
    
            insert into myschema.t_tables (tablename, sizemb, rowcounts, created)
SELECT 
   table_name as tablename,
   (pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) / 1024 /1024) sizemb,
   reltuples as rowcounts, NOW() FROM information_schema.tables ist
left join pg_class pc on pc.relname = ist.table_name
   WHERE table_schema = 'myschema';
  
  exception
                    when others then
                        raise notice ' >> Error for schem.myprocedure()>> % %', sqlerrm, sqlstate;
                      
            end ;
    
     
END;
$procedure$
;
```

Comment: Why are you using the `information_schema.tables`? Eliminate that join and just query from `pg_class` directly.

Comment: 1) Works for me here. Comment out the `exception` portion of the above and add the complete error message to your question. 2) Are you running the procedure as a user with sufficient privileges?